# how to use units along function parameter values in Mathematica

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, units-of-measurement

I would like to pass the parameter values in meters or kilometers (both possible) and get the result in meters/second.

I've tried to do this in the following example:

```
u = 3.986*10^14 Meter^3/Second^2;
v[r_, a_] := Sqrt[u (2/r - 1/a)];

Convert[r, Meter];

Convert[a, Meter];
```

If I try to use the defined function and conversion:

```
a = 24503 Kilo Meter;
s = 10198.5 Meter/Second;
r = 6620 Kilo  Meter;
Solve[v[r, x] == s, x]
```

The function returns the following:

```
{x -> (3310. Kilo Meter^3)/(Meter^2 - 0.000863701 Kilo Meter^2)}
```

which is not the user-friendly format.

Anyway I would like to define a and r in meters or kilometers and get the result s in meters/second (Meter/Second).

I would be very thankful if anyone of you could correct the given function definition and other statements in order to get the wanted result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one way of doing it, where you use the fact that `Solve` returns a list of rules to substitute a value for `x` into `v[r, x]`, and then use `Convert`, which will do the necessary simplification of the resulting algebraic expression as well:

```
With[{rule = First@Solve[v[r,x]==s,x] 
      (* Solve always returns a list of rules, because algebraic 
         equations may have multiple solutions. *)},
  Convert[v[r,x] /. rule, Meter/Second]]
```

This will return `(10198.5 Meter)/Second` as your answer.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to tell Mathematica to simplify the expression assuming that the units are "possitive", which is the reason why it doesn't do the simplifications itself. So, something like

```
SimplifyWithUnits[blabla_, unit_List]:= Simplify[blalba, (#>0)&/@unit];
```

So if you get that ugly thing, you then just type %~SimplifyWithUnits~{Meter} or whatever.